# Format reference and subref of subcaption

Tags: captions, subfloats, subcaption

Is it possible to format the `\ref` and `\subref` of a subcaption completely independently?

The manual suggests changing `thesubfigure` to change the the label of a subfigure and hence the output of `\ref`, but then this affect `\subref` as well.

For example, the following MWE

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{tikz}

% and example figure
\def\exfigure#1#2{
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}\path[draw=#1,fill=#1!20] (0,0) rectangle
      (4,4);\end{tikzpicture}
    \renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{#1}%
    \phantomsubcaption%
    \label{#2}%
  \end{subfigure}\hfill}

\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{subreffig}{(\emph{#2})}
\captionsetup{subrefformat=subreffig}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \exfigure{red}{subfig1}
  \exfigure{green}{subfig2}
  \exfigure{blue}{subfig3}
  \caption{Three squares. Left: \subref{subfig1}. Center: \subref{subfig2}.
    Right: \subref{subfig3}.}
  \label{fig:all}
\end{figure}

In \cref{fig:all}, we have three subfigures \cref{subfig1}
\cref{subfig2} and \cref{subfig3}.
\end{document}
```

The figure has the following caption

> Figure 1: Three squares. Left: (*red*). Center: (*green*). Right: (*blue*).

This is the output I am after. However, the text afterwards has

> In fig. 1, we have three subfigures fig. 1red fig. 1green and fig. 1blue.

Is it possible to change it to

> In fig. 1, we have three subfigures fig. 1-[red] fig. 1-[green] and fig. 1-[blue].

Changing the definition of `\thesubfigure` to

```
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{-[#1]}%
```

gives the correct output in text, but the wrong output in the caption.

Comment: First, \subref{foo} is equivalent to \ref{sub@foo}.  Rather than modify subcaption (which in turn modifies \label) it would be easier to create a new \label containing your desired format.

Comment: If I change the definition to `\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{-[#1]}`, `\cref` seems to work as expected (so that the reference has the correct format).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it to work without cleveref.  Both subcaption and cleveref (not to mention hyperref) modify `\label` in many ways, producing a legion of `\newlabel` commands in the aux file.  So I went back to basics and used `\protected@write` instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
%\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\sublabel}[1]{\refstepcounter{subfigure}%
  \protected@write\@auxout{}{\string\newlabel{sub@#1}{{(\string\emph{\thesubfigure})}{\thepage}}}%
  \protected@write\@auxout{}{\string\newlabel{#1}{{\thefigure-[\thesubfigure]}{\thepage}}}}
\makeatother

% and example figure
\def\exfigure#1#2{
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}\path[draw=#1,fill=#1!20] (0,0) rectangle
      (4,4);\end{tikzpicture}
    \renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{#1}%
    \sublabel{#2}%
  \end{subfigure}\hfill}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \exfigure{red}{subfig1}
  \exfigure{green}{subfig2}
  \exfigure{blue}{subfig3}
  \caption{Three squares. Left: \subref{subfig1}. Center: \subref{subfig2}.
    Right: \subref{subfig3}.}
  \label{fig:all}
\end{figure}

In \ref{fig:all}, we have three subfigures \ref{subfig1}
\ref{subfig2} and \ref{subfig3}.
\end{document}
```

---

This version is compatible to both cleveref and hyperref.  The key is to format `\thesubfigure` for `\cref` and `\@currentlabel` for `\ref` and `\subref`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\sublabel}[2]{% #1 = color, #2 = label
  \refstepcounter{subfigure}%
  \edef\@currentlabel{(\noexpand\emph{#1})}\nosublabel{sub@#2}%
  \edef\@currentlabel{\thefigure-[#1]}\nosublabel{#2}%
  \ignorespaces}
\makeatother

% and example figure
\def\exfigure#1#2{\let\nosublabel=\label
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}\path[draw=#1,fill=#1!20] (0,0) rectangle
      (4,4);\end{tikzpicture}
    \renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{-[#1]}% for cref
    \sublabel{#1}{#2}
  \end{subfigure}\hfill}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \exfigure{red}{subfig1}
  \exfigure{green}{subfig2}
  \exfigure{blue}{subfig3}
  \caption{Three squares. Left: \subref{subfig1}. Center: \subref{subfig2}.
    Right: \subref{subfig3}.}
  \label{fig:all}
\end{figure}

In \cref{fig:all}, we have three subfigures \cref{subfig1}
\cref{subfig2} and \cref{subfig3}.
\end{document}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \exfigure{red}{subfig1}
  \exfigure{green}{subfig2}
  \exfigure{blue}{subfig3}
  \caption{Three squares. Left: \subref{subfig1}. Center: \subref{subfig2}.
    Right: \subref{subfig3}.}
  \label{fig:all}
\end{figure}

In \cref{fig:all}, we have three subfigures \cref{subfig1}
\cref{subfig2} and \cref{subfig3}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: While the solution certainly works, isn't it too low-level? even without cleverref. I was hoping to find a way to redefine some `subcaption` commands which set both the label and the `sub@` label. In theory such a method would work for `cref` as well as the original `ref` since `subcaptions` works nicely with both.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution based on the internals of subcaption

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\thesubreffigure}{\thesubfigure}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\subcaption@@label[2]{%
  \@bsphack\begingroup
    \subcaption@ORI@label#1{#2}%
    \let\SK@\@gobbletwo
    \protected@edef\@currentlabel{\csname thesubref\@captype\endcsname}%
    \subcaption@ORI@label#1{sub@#2}%
  \endgroup\@esphack}
\makeatother

% and example figure
\def\exfigure#1#2{
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}\path[draw=#1,fill=#1!20] (0,0) rectangle
      (4,4);\end{tikzpicture}
    % \renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{#1}
    %
    \renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{-[#1]}%
    \renewcommand{\thesubreffigure}{#1}%
    \phantomsubcaption%
    \label{#2}%
  \end{subfigure}\hfill}

\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{subreffig}{(\emph{#2})}
\captionsetup{subrefformat=subreffig}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \exfigure{red}{subfig1}
  \exfigure{green}{subfig2}
  \exfigure{blue}{subfig3}
  \caption{Three squares. Left: \subref{subfig1}. Center: \subref{subfig2}.
    Right: \subref{subfig3}.}
  \label{fig:all}
\end{figure}

In \cref{fig:all}, we have three subfigures \cref{subfig1}
\cref{subfig2} and \cref{subfig3}.
\end{document}
```

Produces the correct output for both `\cref` and `\subref`. Unfortunately does not produce the correct label when setting a caption instead of using `\phantomsubcaption`.